# Email problems with Mail client Mac

Tags: macos, email

The deafult mail client in a Mac cut of the last part of this message. After the image inside the activate link the rest of the email is cut of.

But in iPhone, Windows Phone and outlook i can see al the email

```
    <div style="width: 100%; border-spacing: 0;">
        <div style="background-color: #ffffff;">
            <div style="height: 155px;">
                <img src="http://website.com/static/img/logo.jpg" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="background-color: #cccccc;">
            <div style="height: 5px;"></div>
        </div>
        <div style="background-color: #f2f2f2;">
            <div style="padding: 20px;">
                <p>Some text</p>
                <br />
                <p>
                    <a href="http://website.com/activate/key123">
                        <img src="http://website.com/static/img/landing/img.jpg" />
                    </a>
                </p><p>MoreText</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, in html email you should be using tables, not divs.

Your image tag has no height and width on it which could be the cause of your issue. Generally, your image tag should look like this:

```
<img style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; display: block;" src="" width="" height="" alt="">
```